# List index out of bounds [-1] when making bioclimatic variables in DIVA GIS

Tags: diva-gis, maxent

I am working with climate data and I would like to make 19 bioclimatic variables which I can use for ecolgical niche modeling in Maxent. I am following this tutorial http://www.ccafs-climate.org/downloads/docs/Ramirez_Bueno-Cabrera_2009_tutorial_bcvars_creation.pdf (google: bioclimatic variables + Maxent)

After I create the CLM files in DIVA-GIS, I go to data>climate>map and I receive this error:
"List index out of bounds [-1]".  Has anyone run into such an error and do you know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Diva but MaxEnt prefers ascii files to anything else.  If you can export / save your rasters as .txt files then you can just change the filename to .asc afterwards and your environmental layers should be good to go with MaxEnt.  In addition, double check all your projections.  WGS84 is the way to go.

If you have access to ArcGIS you may find using that easier as the DIVA tutorial seems to jump through unnecessary hoops.